# Images and css are not loading in codeigniter email

Tags: php, html, css

I'm sending an html view in email.Email has been sent successfully but after receiving an email images are not not loading and css are not applying.
Also I'm getting an error with whole html code.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HshY9.png)

```
function send_mail() {
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'demo.example.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'my_smtp_username',
        'smtp_pass' => 'J@kO()FF%u]I',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'starttls' => true,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE,
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n",
        $config['crlf'] = "\r\n"
    );

    $message = '';
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('test@demo.example.com');
    $to_email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->email->to($to_email); // change it to yours
    $mail_data = array(
        'username' => $to_email,
        'password' => random_string('alnum', 16)
    );
    $msg = $this->load->view('YMI/demo.php', $mail_data, true);
    $this->email->subject('Subject');
    $this->email->message($msg);
    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Email sent.';
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
    $this->load->view('YMI/admin/custEmail');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Headers will help set the required format for your email. 
Also if you load your view on site does it fully load as expected?

```
 $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
        $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
```

Comment: Updated my answer. You have to set the headers. so if you copy and paste the above to where you load the library it should work.

Comment: I'm done with the CSS and Images, but after sending email it's not redirecting, it gives the error shown in image